# Derive results if the result contains all values from another table

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to get all the names of the customer who have purchase all the treatment packages (A101, A102, A103)

The following is an illustration of the tables I have:

Customer

```
CustID Surname Given Name
100    White   Layla
101    Wells   Mary
```

Account

```
AcctNo CustID
600    100
601    101
```

AccountLine

```
AcctNo TreatmentNo
600    A102
601    A103
600    A102
600    A101
601    A101
```

Treatment

```
TreatmentNo Description
A101        For face
A102        For body
A103        For legs
```

In my statement, I wrote it as:

```
SELECT c.givenname
FROM accountline al, treatment t, account a, customer c
WHERE al.treatmentno IN (SELECT treatmentno FROM treatment)
AND al.accountno IN (SELECT accountno FROM account)
AND c.custid IN (SELECT custid FROM customer)
GROUPBY c.givenname
```

The results that I derived from the above statement has instead return me customer who have purchase ***any*** of the treatment packages. Help, please?

P.S - I cannot display both the given name and family name together (`SELECT c.givenname, c.familyname` in my first line) as this results in an error stating `not a GROUP BY expression`, why is that so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the below - use a `having clause` to check who've purchased all three products

```
SELECT c.givenname,c.familyname
FROM accountline al join treatment t on al.TreatmentNo=t.TreatmentNo
join account a on a.AcctNo=al.AcctNo
join customer c on c.CustID=a.CustID
where t.TreatmentNo in ('A101', 'A102', 'A103')
GROUP BY c.givenname,c.familyname
having count(distinct t.TreatmentNo)=3
```

Comment: Hi, there is an error in your code, in which `GROUPBY` should be `GROUP BY`. Even so, I am getting `00907. 00000 -  "missing right parenthesis"` error

Comment: @j.hall, I've updated the answer - you can give a try

Answer (score 0):

Here is a Similar approach with `OVER` and `PARTITION BY` function.

```
SELECT DISTINCT I.givenname, 
                I.familyname
FROM (SELECT c.givenname,
             c.familyname,
             count(DISTINCT al.TreatmentNo) OVER (PARTITION BY al.AcctNo) as t_count
        FROM accountline al join treatment t on al.TreatmentNo=t.TreatmentNo
             join account a on a.AcctNo=al.AcctNo
             join customer c on c.CustID=a.CustID
       WHERE t.TreatmentNo in ('A101', 'A102', 'A103')) I
WHERE I.t_count = 3;
```